# Explanation of signal.find_peaks() approach

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I have looked through the `scipy.signal` docs for an explanation of the peak finding approach used in `find_peaks()` and have been unable to find an explanation similar to the excellent explanation given but the cwt peak finding approach.

Is anyone here able to explain the peak finding approach used by the `find_peaks()` function

I am looking for a explanation specifically of the algorithmic implementation of the function as opposed to an explanation of it’s usage

Comment: It says "This function takes a 1-D array and finds all local maxima by **simple comparison of neighboring values**." It's just straightforward comparison of neighboring values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html)
has a Show Source link which reveals:

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.10.1/scipy/signal/_peak_finding.py#L835

> a peak or local maximum is defined as any sample whose two direct neighbours have a smaller amplitude.

and it goes on to gather the raw features from this routine:

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.10.1/scipy/signal/_peak_finding_utils.pyx#L64

Likely you will want to run Gaussian blurring
over your noisy data, or windowed median or some other
technique prior to asking for peaks.
Or follow their advice to prefer `find_peaks_cwt`.

The documentation includes some nice illustrations
of how different parameter settings will change
the number of spurious detected peaks according
to your data's pattern. Mostly we're putting a simple box
around each candidate peak to see if it should
survive the filtering step.
Read the (short!) corresponding `if` clause
for each diagram which isn't immediately clear.

Think about adding np.random.uniform(high=a) to b * sine_wave.
Depending on the magnitudes of `a` and `b` you might find
peaks at nearly every 2π interval. Or you might find a
multitude of local maxima within a single half-wave.
So smoothing will strongly affect peak detection performance.

Consider using this approach:

1. For some window of samples, find the peak-to-peak amplitude -- it will be 2.0 for pure sin(), more for noisy sin().
2. Pick some threshold fraction of amplitude, perhaps 80%.
3. Set all samples below threshold to minimum value.
4. Do peak detection on this (much simpler) dataset.

Comment: You don't need to go to the source to get that quote - it's right there in the documentation, under "Notes".

Comment: I used the single citation link to introduce the "goes on to" a `_local_maxima_1d()` call. The docs quite rightly don't tell us about that private helper. But looking at the pair of functions together we see the identical definition of "peak" in the docstrings, and then it starts to make sense.